# Последовательный подсчет слов в строке

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, list

Задача: вывести True, если в строке последовательно находятся три слова, в противном случае вывести False. В строке есть числа и слова. Мой код некорректно работает в случае если между словами расположены числа. Добавление условия `result != []` не решило проблему, а больше идей у меня нет.

```
import re
def checkio(words: str) -> bool:
    str_ = words.split()
    sum_ = 0
    for i in str_:
        result = re.findall(r'[\w*\']+', i)
        if len(result)!=0 and result != []:
            sum_ = sum_+ 1
    if sum_ >= 3:
        return True
    else:
        return False    


#These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Example:')
    print(checkio("Hello World hello"))

    assert checkio("Hello World hello") == True, "Hello"
    assert checkio("He is 123 man") == False, "123 man"
    assert checkio("1 2 3 4") == False, "Digits"
    assert checkio("bla bla bla bla") == True, "Bla Bla"
    assert checkio("Hi") == False, "Hi"
    print("Coding complete? Click 'Check' to review your tests and earn cool rewards!")
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение с помощью регулярного выражения:

```py
import re


def checkio(words: str) -> bool:
    return bool(re.match(r'.*[a-zA-Z]+\s+[a-zA-Z]+\s+[a-zA-Z]+.*', words))
```

*Тесты:*

```py
print(checkio('13 holy hand grenade'))    # True
print(checkio('holy grenade'))            # False
print(checkio('13 666 777'))              # False
print(checkio(' eggs  eggs  eggs '))      # True
print(checkio('spam 13 spam spam'))       # False
print(checkio('eggs 13 eggs eggs eggs'))  # True
print(checkio('spam13 eg_gs eggs'))       # False
```

Comment: `'foo bar1 bar2'` ?

Comment: @strawdog IMHO, цифры, как и нижнее подчёркивание, в словах не используют, но поправить это крайне легко.

Answer (score 1):

Логика:

```
for i in str_:
        если слово:  #        if not i.isdigit():  или регуляркой
            sum_ = sum_+ 1
            if sum_ >= 3:
                return True
        else:
            sum_ = 0    
return False
```

Answer (score 1):

А обязательно регуляркой?
можно ещё так, например:

```
import itertools as it

def checkit(a: str):
    if len(list(it.takewhile(lambda x: not x.isnumeric(), a.split())))>2:
        return True
    else:
        return False

checkit('hello1 1 world hello 2') #False
checkit('hello1 world hello 2') #True
```

Comment: `13 spam spam spam` вернёт `False`, несмотря на то, что в этой строке _"последовательно находятся три слова"_. Аналогично с `word 13 word word word`. Думаю, что нужно учитывать такие конструкции, исходя из формулировки вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

C использованием регулярного выражения (выбирает три подряд идущих слова, которые могут содержать цифры, но не должны быть числом):

```
import re
def checkio(words: str) -> bool:
    return bool(re.findall(r'(?:\b(?:\d+[^\d\s]\w*|[^\s\d]\w+)\b\s*){3}', words))

#These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Example:')
    assert checkio("Hello World hello") == True, "Hello"
    assert checkio("He is 123 man") == False, "123 man"
    assert checkio("1 2 3 4") == False, "Digits"
    assert checkio("bla bla bla bla") == True, "Bla Bla"
    assert checkio("Hi") == False, "Hi"
    assert checkio("13 holy hand grenade") == True, "grenade1"
    assert checkio("holy grenade") == False, "grenade2"
    assert checkio("13 666 777") == False, "Digits"
    assert checkio(" eggs  eggs  eggs ") == True, "eggs1"
    assert checkio("spam 13 spam spam") == False, "spam"
    assert checkio("eggs 13 eggs eggs eggs") == True, "eggs2"
    assert checkio("spam13 eg_gs eggs") == True, "eggs3"
    print("Coding complete? Click 'Check' to review your tests and earn cool rewards!")
```

**Обновил:**

1. шаблон, для поддержки слов, содержащих цифры.
2. Заменил `re.match()` -> `re.findall()`

Comment: а что будет, если в слове есть цифра?

Comment: Не работает. Например, `spam 1 spam spam spam` вернёт `False`

Comment: @strawdog, про цифру упустил из внимания - обновил шаблон в ответе.

Comment: @nomnoms12, спасибо, исправил.